# Locally install a gem built with platform=java | JRuby 1.7.18

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

It seems that the workflow that I use to build and install gems locally does not translate when the gemspec has platform = "java".

I am using Jruby 1.7.18, installed with rvm

```
$ which gem
/Users/USERNAME/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.18/bin/gem
```

When I build a gem with the default platform, everything goes according to plan:

```
$ grep platform batching_core.gemspec 
  # spec.platform      = "java"

$ gem build batching_core.gemspec 
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: batching_core
  Version: 0.1.0
  File: batching_core-0.1.0.gem

$ gem install batching_core-0.1.0.gem 

jar dependencies found on non-java platform gem - do not install jars

Successfully installed batching_core-0.1.0
1 gem installed
```

Note the success message of "Successfully installed batching_core-0.1.0"

But when my project requires me to use platform=java so that I can require some jar files. I can build the gem, but I cannot install it. The installation ends without the success message, and I cannot require the gem in irb:

```
$ grep platform batching_core.gemspec 
  spec.platform      = "java"

$ gem build batching_core.gemspec 
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: batching_core
  Version: 0.1.0
  File: batching_core-0.1.0-java.gem

$ gem install batching_core-0.1.0-java.gem 
$
```

^^ Note the lack of output. No success message, no output at all.

```
$ irb
jruby-1.7.18 :001 > require 'batching_core'
LoadError: no such file to load -- batching_core
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071:in `require'
    from /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.18/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I tried the solution suggested here, but got the same result.
[Creating a gem using Jruby and not Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433839/creating-a-gem-using-jruby-and-not-ruby)

EDIT: Here's the project that causes the issue:

https://github.com/ValerieAnne563/so34754484

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the gem does not contain the file you're trying to require. Can you check the contents to see if "batching_core.rb" is in the gem's lib dir?

As for the warning...I'm confused about your environment. This is a gem with a jar in it being installed on JRuby? Maybe it would clarify some things if you link to the project or post the gemspec.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And yep, lib/batching_core.rb does exist in the gem. The FNF seems to come from the gem not being installed at all.  If I were to build the gem under the default platform, that same require happens without issue.

Comment: `jruby-1.7.18 :004 >   require 'fubar' `
`LoadError: no such file to load -- fubar`
               `from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071:in require `

Comment: For clarity of the question, I updated the gemspec (and console outputs) to resolve the warnings. The issue persists.

Comment: The gem does not have jars in it. Rather bundle install creates a lib/batching_core_jars.rb with maven descriptors for the jars specified in the gemspec. I got the idea from: https://github.com/mkristian/jar-dependencies/tree/master/examples/gem-with-jar-dependencies

Comment: Ok, my next guess...are you actually installing with the "gem" from JRuby? Or perhaps are GEM_* env vars set to some unexpected location?

Comment: When I gem install with the default platform in the gemspec, it creates a directory under $GEM_HOME/ that looks like an exploded gem:  /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18/gems/batching_core-0.1.0/  This looks like it's under jruby. Could the other install w/ `platform = "java" ` put it somewhere else? I don't get `Successfully installed batching_core-0.1.0` when `platform = "java"`